# What's the Difference between Remark & Rehype?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, remarkjs, mdxjs

I'm a bit confused. I think remark is a markdown processor, rehype is an html processor. So remark takes some markdown, transforms it, and gives me back some markdown. Rehype takes some html, transforms it, and gives me back some html - is this correct?

For example: I came across the packages [`remark-slug`](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-slug) and [`rehype-slug`](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-slug), and they appear to do basically the same thing—what is the difference between the two?

Comment: for reference, I found these articles helpful: 1. [An Introduction to Unified and Remark](https://braincoke.fr/blog/2020/03/an-introduction-to-unified-and-remark), 2. [Transforming Markdown with Remark & Rehype](https://www.ryanfiller.com/blog/remark-and-rehype-plugins), 3. [How to debug unified, rehype, or remark and fix bugs in markdown processing](https://swizec.com/blog/how-to-debug-unified-rehype-or-remark-and-fix-bugs-in-markdown-processing-2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not quite right. [remark](https://remark.js.org/) and [rehype](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype#readme) are [Node.js-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) processors in the [unified collective](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams). They support parsing [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) respectively to/from [syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). All such processors in the [unified collective](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams) support '*plugins*' that enable you to inspect and manipulate the intermediary [syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Powerful stuff.

[remark-slug](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-slug/tree/8e6394c#remark-slug) and [rehype-slug](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-slug#rehype-slug) are third-party plugins for their respective [unified collective](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams) processors, [remark](https://remark.js.org/) and [rehype](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype#readme). From the *slugs'* descriptions I gather these plugins are used to turn "*headings*" into navigable items (Anchors/Bookmarks).

You decide what to use based on your input and output formats and what, if any, inspection or transformation you want to accomplish. You may use some or all of them.

Comment: "You may use some or all of them..." or, create your own plug-in(s).

Comment: Here's another's take [Transforming Markdown with Remark & Rehype, When to use Each](https://www.ryanfiller.com/blog/remark-and-rehype-plugins#when-to-use-each) - Ryan Filler.

Answer (score 0):

`remark` unified processor with support for parsing from markdown and serializing to markdown.

`rehype` unified processor to add support for parsing from HTML and serializing to HTML.